# Way to obtain the list of test methods from the excluded group

Tags: annotations, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

My setup is like below:
I run my TestNG test with `excludedGroups` Maven Surefire Plugin parameter set to `failing`. So, test methods which are known to be failing are excluded from the test suite.

I want to obtain the list of those test methods.

I did not find a straightforward solution for this.

Does anyone know how to do it? Whether it can be done using capabilities of Java, Annotations, TestNG or Maven...

Answer (score 1):

Couple of ways : Implement Isuitelistener->onStart method.  Use the `suite.getExcludedMethods` to get a list of all excluded methods calculated.  You can implement ITestListener as well and use `context.getExcludedMethods/Groups` for the list too.